# highstock display tooltip wrong in iframe

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-8, highcharts

I am showing my page which contains highstock in iframe. The tooltip can't display correctly,it always away from mouse pointer. but if the page accessed directly without iframe the tooltip display correctly. This error happens only in IE8. In chrome/IE9+ it works well. Could you please suggest a solution for this.

```
You can see my test page at http://61.234.191.188:18181/TestWeb/test.html
```

Comment: Which version of IE8 do you use, because in my it works properly.

Comment: Do you visit my test page?If it works well.

Comment: Yes I opened, after a few minutes, but in my IE8 it looks like fine, I cannot reproduce this issue, co could you supply version of yours IE?

Comment: I test in IE10.0.9200.16540 using IE8 mode.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same issue as jQuery's [ticket #12343](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12343), which they marked can't fix since there is no way of detecting when it applies and not. The best workaround I suppose is to make sure your application runs in Standards mode, which will also cause the Highcharts charts to run in SVG which is multitudes faster.